# How to pass filename through variable to be read it by awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Good day,

I was wondering how to pass the filename to awk as variable, in order to awk read it.

So far I have done:

```
echo    file1   >  Aenumerar
echo    file2   >> Aenumerar
echo    file3   >> Aenumerar

AE=`grep -c '' Aenumerar`
r=1
while [ $r -le $AE ]; do
    lista=`awk "NR==$r {print $0}" Aenumerar`
    AEList=`grep -c '' $lista`
    s=1
    while [ $s -le $AEList ]; do
        word=`awk -v var=$s 'NR==var {print $1}' $lista`
        echo $word
    let "s = s + 1"
    done
let "r = r + 1"
done
```

Thanks so much in advance for any clue or other simple way to do it with bash command line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
awk "NR==$r {print $0}" Aenumerar
```

You need to use:

```
awk -v r="$r" 'NR==r' Aenumerar
```

Comment: +1: @Alejandro: Read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Shell-Variables.html) for more details.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that those two commands are equivalent (provided `$r` is actually a valid integer), aside from the problem of `$0` being expanded by Bash before calling AWK. Can you explain why you think they're different?

Comment: That's true, `$0` is being expanded

Answer (score 5):

Judging by what you've posted, you don't actually need all the `NR` stuff; you can replace your whole script with this:

```
while IFS= read -r lista ; do
    awk '{print $1}' "$lista"
done < Aenumerar
```

(This will print the first field of each line in each of `file1`, `file2`, `file3`. I think that's what you're trying to do?)